# Møller scattering: twisted?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, scattering, feynman-diagrams, s-matrix-theory

I am studying the [Møller scattering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B8ller_scattering), but I don't know how to get the twisted diagram from the S-matrix. Has anybody a good explanation?

Comment: Could you be more clear on what do you mean by "twisted diagram"?